# Exporting to CSV CP1252 West encoding french accent characters not converting

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am exporting customer names (and street addresses) form my e-commerce store and we have many French customer names that are causing some issues with the export to CSV. I thought I had fixed it by using utf8_decode() as follows:

```
echo utf8_decode($row['billing_name']) . ",";
```

The $row['billing_name'] is coming from a simply while loop from a mysqli database query.

but for example Stéphane Perry  is exporting as: St√©phane Perry  in the csv file

I checked the database and the encoding set on the customer field is CP1252 West Which I assume is to account for french accents so I don't think I want to mess with the encoding on there and I am hoping for fix I can use during the export.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any encode/decode routines.  They are likely to just make things worse.  I think that is part of what happened here.

`é`, when mojibaked, turns into `Ã©`.  However, I can't find a path to `√©`.  Do you have another example (involving a different letter)?  Where is "CP1252 West" specified?  (That is not a MySQL charset.)

If possible please provide

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

to show the internal encoding of some text.  We also need to figure out whether the problem occurred during `INSERT` or during `SELECT` (or both).  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the datatype.